# Toolbar desaparece quando adiciono outro widget na activity

Tags: android, menu

Criei um Toolbar para a MainActivity, conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: Toolbar funcionando]

Porém, quando adiciono qualquer outro widget na mesma activity, a toolbar desaparece ao executar o emulador:

[image: Toolbar sumiu]

Alguém já teve o mesmo problema ou sabe como resolver?

Código toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Código menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline_black_24dp"
    android:title="Adicionar outro item"
    android:id="@+id/adicionarItem"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    />
<item
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_save_black_24dp"
    android:title="Salvar lista"
    android:id="@+id/salvarLista"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    />
</menu>
```

Código activity_main.xml (sem adicionar outro widget):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="lucaspereira.listadecompras.MainActivity">

<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Código MainActivity.java:

```
...
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
        case R.id.adicionarItem:

            break;
        case R.id.salvarLista:

            break;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Experimente colocar um  `android:layout_below="@id/include"` no `TextView`.

Comment: O problema é que quando você coloca um `id` na `include`, o `id` atribuído nela será passado para a view que ela representa. Ou seja, o Id da toolbar acaba ficando como 'include'.

Comment: @acklay tentei e acontece o mesmo problema.

Comment: @IAMLuc quando adiciono um novo widget, esse `id` é atribuído automaticamente na `include`.

Comment: Tenta colocar a toolbar sem utilizar a include...

Comment: @Lucas esta resposta inclusa responde essa questão. Nunca tinha me deparado com isso. Abs. boa sorte.

Answer (score 0):

O erro ocorre quando o `id` do seu `<include>` é diferente `findViewById(R.id.toolbar);`. No seu caso está `android:id="@+id/include"`. Veja um exemplo abaixo:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
```

Na classe:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

E para que qualquer outra *view* fique abaixo, é necessário definir propriedade do `android:layout_below` referenciando o id do seu `<include>`. Veja:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/include"
    android:text="Caraca funfou!" />
```

Comment: Implementa sua resposta com isto aqui: para utilizar com ids diferentes, ao tentar criar uma referência para a toolbar, primeiro é necessário tbm criar uma referência para a Include.

Comment: `View include = findViewById(R.id.include);` e depois para a toolbar: `Toolbar appBar = (Toolbar) include.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);`